# Page auto reload without refresh

Tags: asynchronous, refresh, reload

Hi
I want to know How to make the page reload asynchronous, for example if someone has received a message , the last message will appear without refreshing the page. just like facebook. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use something like JQuery & Javascript to poll the server for changes and display them on the page in a div.

```
setInterval('someFunc()', 1000)

function someFunc()
{

 $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "www.domain.com/url",
            data: data,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#myDiv").html(html);                
            }  
        });

}
```

This will update the div with ID myDiv every second with the data from www.domain.com/url passing in *data* is a param (you will have to define 'data')

Answer (score 1):

well there is alot of approaches
but the basics is that you call an ajax function every second or so that
checks with external php/asp or whatever file if any changes has been made to your
database/text if so 
append it to the chatbox.

p.s. using libraries such as [jquery](http://jquery.com) simplifies things alot

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) model, it doesn't stress the network so much and does not fill the web servers access logs so much. The responses are also faster. Commet means that the HTTP server pushes the data to you immediately when they appear.